# Request.QueryString cannot be used in this way

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httprequest

I'm trying to retrieve the values from the Url using the second function. the first function function passes in the checkedValue variable and the second should check to see if the category is there and if it is return the value.

```
Imports System.Web.HttpRequest

Public Class ReviewPageDefault
Inherits Page

Shared Function GetProductId()

    Dim util As New Utilities

    Dim product = ""

    If util.CheckString("schoolid") = "" And util.CheckString("stockid") = "" Then
        product = (util.CheckString("stock"))
    ElseIf util.CheckString("stock") = "" And util.CheckString("stockid") = "" Then
        product = (util.CheckString("FN"))
    Else
        Dim stockId = util.CheckString("stockid")
        product = stockId
    End If
    Return product

End Function

End Class

Public Class Utilities
Inherits Page

Public Function CheckString(checkedValue As String)

    Dim check = ""
    If Request.QueryString(checkedValue) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        check = Request.QueryString(checkedValue)
    End If
    Return check

End Function

End Class
```

However whenever I try to test the page I get the error

```
System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context
```

The code is located in the code behind for an asp.net page, that attempts to retrieve the product value

```
<script>
    var product = '<%= ReviewPageDefault.GetProductId()%>';
</script>
```

I've searched the internet over and have found nothing, any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: Where is this code located? In which class? Does it have access to the HTTP request?

Comment: Yes it does, it is located in its own 'Utilities' class and inherits the HTTPRequest

Comment: `and inherits the HTTPRequest` - I would be very interested how you managed to inherit from a sealed class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx Or is this some HTTPRequest class of yours? Also where are you calling this method - inside a webform, Application_Start, ...?

Comment: I mistyped, I **import** the System.Web.HttpRequest at the top before anything else, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, but in order to use the `QueryString` property you need to first get an instance of this Request class. How are you doing it? What's this `Request` variable pointing to?

Comment: If it would help I could add the code that is calling this function

Comment: Yes it would help and also where is this code located.

Comment: Okay I revised the question and added more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Utilities class take the Request as parameter instead of inheriting from Page:

```
Public Class Utilities

    Public Function CheckString(checkedValue As String, request as HttpRequest)

        Dim check = ""
        If request.QueryString(checkedValue) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            check = request.QueryString(checkedValue)
        End If
        Return check

    End Function

End Class
```

and when calling it pass the Request from the main page:

```
util.CheckString("stock", Request)
```

or make it an [`extension method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) on the [`HttpRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class so that you can use it like this:

```
Request.CheckString("stock")
```

Comment: It won't allow me to pass Request from the main page because it's a shared function and Request is a non-shared member, any way to bypass that?

Comment: OK, so you need to pass the Request as parameter to this shared function. The request is only available inside the webform that inherits from Page. So in your markup: `var product = '<%= ReviewPageDefault.GetProductId(Request)%>';`. And now the `GetProductId` function will have access to it. Alternatively make this as an extension method to the HttpRequest class - it will make it easier and you will not need to explicitly pass the Request as parameter to those static functions.